# How can I set a default path in FolderBrowser retrieved from app.config?

Tags: vb.net, app-config, folderbrowserdialog

I'm trying to save user defined path in *app.config*, and set the same as default path to a **FolderBrowser** next time the app is run.

Seems I'm saving the path, but couldn't set it as Default, *next time*. Please help me pointing towards where I'm missing something.

````
    Public Sub SaveDoc(document As Document)
     DefaultPath = "..\\Screen Captures\\"
     FolderBrowserDialog1.RootFolder = Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop

     FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath = My.Settings.UserPathSettings
     If (FolderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK) Then
      UserPath = FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath & "\\"
      My.Settings.UserPathSettings = UserPath
      My.Settings.Save()
     Else
      UserPath = DefaultPath
     End If
     MsgBox(UserPath) ' Just to check is same is getting saved in app.config!
     MsgBox(My.Settings.UserPathSettings) ' Just to check is same is getting saved in app.config!
     .
     'Ommitted more Codes...
     .
    End Sub```
````

Also, I added below line under ***Form_Load()*** - Without knowing what to do:
`FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath = My.Settings.UserPathSettings`

I need to get the user given path next time the app is run. Which is still pointing to root Desktop Dir.

Please let me know in the comments if you need anything. Your help is appreciated!

[First Run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HelVm.png)

[Msgbox Displaying path I selected instead of Desktop(by browsing...)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSYvZ.png)

[Second Run - still shows default root as Desktop :(](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgDQw.png)

[Settings - Value is blank - Anything to do here?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVH6z.png)

Comment: Did you translate some C# code? This: ``\\`` doesn't work in VB.Net; also you don't need to add a slash to the path. Remove this: `DefaultPath = "..\\Screen Captures\\"`, it's wrong and forders must specify an absolute path. Use: `UserPath = FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath`. You can also remove `FolderBrowserDialog1.RootFolder = Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop`, it's already the default root path.

Comment: Thanks @Jimi for the suggestions. The `DefaultPath = "..\\Screen Captures\\"` is added when user doesn't select any custom path(Cancel/Close), the it saves the file in project parent dir. Removing it while its working fine - let me skip it. And regarding the `.RootFolder`, I've removed it. But it still doesn't help me retrieving the saved path. FolderBrowser again opens up to Desktop :(

Comment: This: `"..\\Screen Captures\\"` is not a valid path and VB.Net does not use ``\\`` as path separator Use `System.IO.Path.Combine` to build paths. You need to re-read the remarks section of [FolderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog.selectedpath). Once you have fixed the errors, the project's settings will be fine. Note that User settings are not stored in the `app.config` file, but `\[CurrentUser]\AppData\Local\[ProjectName]\URI\[Version]\user.config`. In `app.config` you have default settings (read-only).

Comment: Thanks @Jimi! I'll proceed as you pointed.